# MissingComponentException unity2D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I can't set my camera options. When I play the game and load another scene the camera options changes. But when I hit play for the same scene it works correctly!!! and the console said :

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Camera' attached to the
>   "Canvas" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
>
> You probably need to add a Camera to the game object "Canvas". Or your
>   script needs to check if the component is attached before using it."

Here is my current script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PixelPerfectCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public static float PixelsToUnits = 1f;
    public static float scale = 1f;

    public Vector2 nativeResolution = new Vector2(400, 160);


    void Awake()
    {

         var camera =  GetComponent<Camera>();


        if (camera.orthographic)
        {
            scale = Screen.height / nativeResolution.y;
            PixelsToUnits *= scale;
            camera.orthographicSize = (Screen.height / 2.0f) / PixelsToUnits;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You **don't** have a camera attached to the-same GameObject the `PixelPerfectCamera`  script is attached to.

If there is only one camera in your scene, change

```
var camera =  GetComponent<Camera>();
```

to

```
Camera camera = Camera.main; //Use the main camera
```

If you have **multiple** camera in your scene then use:

```
Camera camera = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectCameraIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<Camera>(); //Use the main camera
```

You must **change** `NameOfGameObjectCameraIsAttachedTo` to the name of **GameObject** that Camera is attached to.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Script To this :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PixelPerfectCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public static float PixelsToUnits = 1f;
    public static float scale = 1f;

    public Vector2 nativeResolution = new Vector2(400, 160);
    public Camera camera;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (camera.orthographic)
        {
            scale = Screen.height / nativeResolution.y;
            PixelsToUnits *= scale;
            camera.orthographicSize = (Screen.height / 2.0f) / PixelsToUnits;
        }
    }
}
```

Then Attach your camera in the scene to this script's camera field.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a look at RequireComponent, its no requirement, but it helps a lot with such issues.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html